# Where do you need scripting in browsers?

Tags: browser, scripting

Browsers, like Elinks, support scripting. Where do you need it?

**[Clarification]** I meant where users need to do their own scripts. It must do something with data manipulation and extraction. Can scripts help me to become faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting allows a pages to contain executable content. This may be used for custom rendering, interactivity (without round-trip to the server), or ... use your imagination.